# JSON result in MVC print in <pre> tags

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, webclient

so I am trying to show Json result from the method below, and show it in pre tags to see clearly what's going on in the text.

```
    [OutputCache(Duration=300)]
    public ActionResult Foo()
    {
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        var link = new Uri("http://eu.battle.net/wow/en/feed/news");
        var infoFromLinku = wc.DownloadData(link);
        string sContent = string.Empty;
        sContent = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(infoFromLinku);

        return Json(sContent, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

and in View:

```
<div>
<pre>
@Html.Action("Foo", "Home")
</pre>
</div>
```

to look like on picture 1, but all I get is a total mess like on picture 2.

picture 1:
[image: picture 1]

picture 2:
[image: picture 2]

Can someone help me with this one?

So I have tried serializing this xml, without a success. Here is what I have tried:

```
System.Web.Helpers.Json.Encode/Decode
```

and also

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(sContent);
string jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(doc);
```

@one more edit

All I'm trying to do is change this php code into a mvc version. in php it is like 4 lines of code..

```
$sContent = file_get_contents($url);
$simpleXml = simplexml_load_string($sContent);
$json = json_encode($simpleXml);
$result = json_decode($json, TRUE);
```

maybe this will help as well.

Comment: `infoFromLink` returns xml but your code is *claiming* it's json - it's not surprising it's not formatting it correctly.  Try just returning the string result `return Content(sContent)`

Comment: @freedomn-m I've made an edit, could you look at it and maybe suggest some way to serialize this data?

Answer (score 1):

> Return a Partial View, Assign your Json string to ViewBag.yourJsonstring

```
 [OutputCache(Duration=300)]
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    var link = new Uri("http://eu.battle.net/wow/en/feed/news");
    var infoFromLinku = wc.DownloadData(link);
    string sContent = string.Empty;
    sContent = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(infoFromLinku);
    ViewBag.yourJsonstring  = sContent;
    return PartialView("_YourPartialView");
}
    and in PartailView

<div><pre>@ViewBag.yourJsonstring</pre></div>
```

Other Way: You can serialize you json with model objects and can bind in view

Comment: Vivek, have tried the link in your answer? it returns **rss**, not json.

Comment: It is formated in pre tags now, but it is not exactly what I am looking for, it shows me all the html code for that site  only.

Comment: Just a quick comment. I want to get into the tags seens above like \u003centry, which is entry tag for example.

Comment: @Ken'ichiMatsuyama your site returns an xml and you want to process a json, how will that happen....

Comment: @EZI I've made an edit, could you look at it and maybe suggest some way to serialize this data?

Comment: First deserialize as list using model object and use for each loop in view to bind the objects to html tags

Comment: @VivekRanjan Could you tell me what tool should I use to deserialize? I feel like I've tried almost everything..